# ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, math

Estoy haciendo una calculadora muy simple de logaritmos para facilitarme las cosas en el colegio, pero por algún motivo, no funciona a la perfección.

```
 import math

base = input("Introduzca base:")
if base == None:
  base = 2,71828
argumento = input("Introduzca argumento: ")
respuesta = math.log(float(argumento),float(base))
print(respuesta)
```

El problema que tengo es que no sé como hacer que cuando no se le especifica una base, que utilice 2,71828

Comment: Si no ingresas nada en el input, te devuelve una cadena vacía y no None, solo pon `if base=="":`

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. La pregunta es bastante correcta, pero te aconsejo que pongas un título más identificativo. Al fin y al cabo aquí todo el mundo viene pidiendo ayuda con su código.

Comment: Y la base se escribiría con punto en vez de coma, es decir, `2.71828`. O mejor aún, `base = math.e`, pues esa constante la tiene predefinida python en el módulo `math` con mucha mejor precisión de la que le estabas dando.

Answer (score 0):

Como menciona @Christian en el comentario, el input te devuelve una cadena, en dado caso que no insertes nada, te devuelve una cadena vacia `""`. Ademas, no pongas el valor de *e* manualmente, mejor coloca el valor con una libreria que te permita colocarle todos los decimales; numpy, el primero que se me viene a la mente, tiene esta ventaja y quedaría algo como...

```
import numpy as np

base = input("Introduzca base:")
if base == "":
  base = np.exp(1)#Te devuelve el valor 
argumento = input("Introduzca argumento: ")
respuesta = math.log(float(argumento),float(base))
print(respuesta)
```

Si tus bases solamente serán logaritmo natural y 2 numpy te lo simplifica con los 2 métodos por separado
Logaritmo Natural(base 10):

```
N=5
res = np.log(N)
print(res)    # Imprime:  1.609
```

Logaritmo Base 2:

```
N=5
res = np.log2( N )
print(res)    # Imprime:  2.3219
```

Y para exponencial:

```
N=5
res = np.exp( N )
print(res)    # Imprime:  148.413
```

Espero te funcione, feliz día

Comment: No veo necesidad de usar numpy. Si el usuario tiene ya esa librería instalada no hay problema, pero en caso contrario no le aconsejaría instalarla sólo para esto. La biblioteca `math` tiene funciones logarítmicas que valen perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, el problema estaba en que escribiste el número flotante como si fuesen dos números enteros, en vez de 2,71 te ha detectado 2 y 71... Tienes que ponerlo con decimal inglés. Por cierto, la librería que estás usando tiene su propio número e, puedes utilizarlo con math.e.

```
import math

base = float(input("Introduzca base:"))
if not base:
  base = math.e
argumento = float(input("Introduzca argumento: "))
respuesta = math.log(argumento,base)
print(respuesta)
```